# CDI Interceptors: How to intercept `this` calls or get the current proxy object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a class that users will inherit from and implement two methods: `navigateForwards()` and `navigateBackwards()` (it's a wizard-like web application).
The user may want to add interceptors to these methods.

Another class (let's say it's part of a framework) will find the appropriate subclass, `select()` it and call the `navigate(String)` method which will call either `navigateForwards()` or `navigateBackwards()`. At that point interceptors won't work anymore since it's an unproxied method call. I could add interceptors to the `navigate()` method, but that's not the method subclasses are interested in overriding.

Is there an easy way to tell CDI to intercept a method that otherwise wouldn't be intercepted?

I came up with a couple of general approaches to solve this but none of them seems very promising:

1. Somehow get the proxy object that called me. That would require some sort of self-injection that replicates the select() call made in the "framework" class.
2. Get the list of interceptors for the method from CDI and call them manually. Somehow.
3. Use DeltaSpike's EnableInterceptorsProxyFactory http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/proxy.html to wrap `this`. That could be slow and/or uncover other limitations.

There may be another option with CDI extensions, but I'm not sure what an extension is capable of.

I've already tried turning everything upside-down and using decorators instead of a base class in the hopes that a call to the delegate object would get intercepted but it didn't, at least not in JBoss EAP 6.x (most likely 6.4, but it could be an earlier version when I tested).

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to use a decorator and perform the work in the delegate - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhqf.html

Comment: You don't intercept the decorator, that won't work, you add the logic inside the delegate method itself

Comment: Yep, that's a possibility. Is there a way to mimick CDI's annotation processing in the decorator so that the client is unaware that it's not a "real" interceptor? That would effectively be your suggestions combined with number 2 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found (which for some obscure reason hadn't occurred to me before) is making `navigate()` static and passing the object explicitly (e.g. as `self`).

Looking from the outside the class gets a bit weird since it looks like it could have a regular non-static method but has a static one. OTOH it does the job and is easy to understand. I needed the current proxy object so I passed it in. It's trivial and it keeps interceptor behavior.

There are just a few calls that have to be changed in my project, but other projects will have different needs so it isn't a general solution unfortunately. That's why I am not accepting my own answer.